# Character %20 in Post Router

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I'm trying to add new product in my post router, when I submit, I have this error :

```
Cannot POST /admin/%20add-product
```

I don't understand why I have this character %20 in my Route.

I tried to encodeURI in router but it doesn't fix this.

Anyone have a solution to fix this ?

Thanks you all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the encoding. The problem is, that your url is wrong. There should be no space (%20) in it. Check the part where you construct the url and send the request.

Answer (score 1):

`%20` is the [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) variant of a space (" "). Could you share the code how you submit the form?
Probably a space is in there which you have to remove to make it work.